# OctoberCMS error in frontend - frontend is not accessible firing error "Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL"

Tags: php, laravel, runtime-error, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

all
I am new to OctoberCMS, i have installed already built project into my Ubuntu 16.04 system with PHP5.6 and apache2. I have successfully setup and run project backend after very hard trying. but problem is when i open any front-end URL then this error occurs:

> Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL
>   /home/vasim/jannat/code/octoberdev2/plugins/look/casefiles/classes/ActivityLogger.php line 59

[image: error screenshot]

I have search it on Google and can not finding anything helpful and i have also find out that it is a **rainlab** plug-in error, I have uninstall and reinstall that plug-in but that also not worked. so, please can anyone help me with this error?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an error from a plugin called `look/casefiles`. If it's not your own plugin try to remove it and the application should works well.

Comment: Thank you very much @AhmedEssam. I have disabled that **look/casefiles** plugin and error is gone. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely root cause of this is that the plugin was written in PHP 7.x, using typehint `bool` in the method signature. PHP5.6 doesn't support `bool`typehint and interprets `bool` typehint as class and thus the error.

You have some choices:

- Upgrade your project to PHP 7
- See if the plugin is available in PHP 5.x compatible version and use that instead
- Remove the plugin altogether and find another with equivalent functionality
- Remove the plugin and code equivalent functionality yourself
- Fix the error in the plugin yourself (making it backward compatible) **Heads up! It might break when you upgrade the plugin.**

Comment: Thanks @Oli. for your kind response.

Comment: No problem at all